# Iterating through values of a two variables

Tags: for-loop, variables, foreach, terraform

I'm using terraform alb community module to assign IPs to subnets. I managed to do it in three seprate sets (as below). Is there a way to do it one bracket using `for` or `for_each` loop? Thanks!

```
    subnet_mapping =  [
    {
      allocation_id = var.allocation_id[0]
      subnet_id = var.public_subnets[0]
    },
    {
      allocation_id = var.allocation_id[1]
      subnet_id = var.public_subnets[1]
    },
    {
      allocation_id = var.allocation_id[2]
      subnet_id = var.public_subnets[2]
    }
    ]
```

variables.tf

```
variable "public_subnets" {
 type        = list(string)
 description = "Public Subnet ids"
 default     = ["subnet-0b11fb63b479xxxx", "subnet-0f401893ad414xxx", "subnet-0887c57b023fxxx"]
}
variable "allocation_id" {
    type = list(string)
    description = "List of allocation ids of elastic IPs"
    default = ["eipalloc-058fa2edc336f1xxx","eipalloc-012227feb7cf9xxx","eipalloc-075bf28dc2b5cxxx"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/77565922 except for the type definition listing each single attribute

```
variable "subnet_mapping" {
  type = list(object({
            allocation_id = string
            subnet_id     = string
          }))
  default = [
             {allocation_id = "x1", subnet_id = "y1"},
             {allocation_id = "x2", subnet_id = "y2"},
             {allocation_id = "x3", subnet_id = "y3"}
            ]
}


output "subnet_mapping" {
  value = var.subnet_mapping
}
```

Running `terraform apply` yields:

```
subnet_mapping = tolist([
  {
    "allocation_id" = "x1"
    "subnet_id" = "y1"
  },
  {
    "allocation_id" = "x2"
    "subnet_id" = "y2"
  },
  {
    "allocation_id" = "x3"
    "subnet_id" = "y3"
  },
])
```

In any event, creating one variable (list of objects) instead of two lists makes sense because it reduces the possibility of errors.

Answer (score 1):

Creating new "merged" variable fixed my issue

```
variable "subnet_allocation" {
    type = list(map(string))
    description = "List of allocation ids of elastic IPs"
    default = [
        {
            subnet_id = "subnet-03a4e8690b5903xxx"
            allocation_id = "eipalloc-058fa2edc336f1xxx"
        },
        {
            subnet_id = "subnet-0a656c5cc7f1xxx8"
            allocation_id = "eipalloc-012227feb7cxxx3"
        },
        {
            subnet_id = "subnet-07b8b64c8affxxx3"
            allocation_id = "eipalloc-075bf28dc2bxxx7"
        }
    ]
}
```

And changing the main code to

```
    subnet_mapping = var.subnet_allocation
```

Comment: `type = list(object({subnet_id = string, allocation_id = string}))` would be a more specific type constraint here, since your module is presumably assuming that all of the elements have both attributes and so better to specify that in your type constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that using a single variable to pass the whole data structure is typically the best answer, but for completeness here's a more *direct* answer to the question with the data still arriving in two separate variables:

```
locals {
  subnet_allocation = tolist([
    for i, subnet_id in var.public_subnets : {
      subnet_id     = subnet_id
      allocation_id = var.allocation_id[i]
    }
  ])
}
```

This uses the indices from one of the lists to select corresponding elements from the other list. This will work only if they both have the same length, and so the solution of combining them together into a single variable (as shown in another answer to the question) is better in this case because it effectively *forces* there to be a correlation between subnet ids and allocation ids.